# Profile Model in django not saving new update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i trying to create update profile, but its doesnt work
i think its because instance(?) but i cant fix it, please help to solve my problem, i already add my meta form in there

this is my views.py post_update

```
def post_update(request, pk):
    instance = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    instance2 = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user_form = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user , data=request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=instance2)
    postingan = Profile.objects.filter(id=pk)
    postingan2 = User.objects.filter(id=pk)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        instance = user_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return render(request, 'pengurusan/index.html')
    if profile_form.is_valid():
        instance2 = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        instance2.save()
        return render(request, 'pengurusan/index.html')
    context={
        "user_form" : user_form,
        "profile_form" : profile_form,
        "instance2" : instance2,
        "postingan" : postingan,
        "instance" : instance,
        "postingan2" : postingan2,
    }
    return render(request, 'pengurusan/update-form.html', context)
```

and this is my forms.py

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')
    widgets = { 'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'exampleInputEmail', 'placeholder' : 'Email Address', 'name' : 'email'}),
                'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'exampleFirstName', 'placeholder' : 'username', 'name' : 'username'})
    }
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['nama', 'nik', 'email', 'nomor_hp']
        widgets = { 'nama': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'id' : 'exampleFirstName', 'placeholder' : 'Name'}),
                    'nik' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id' : 'exampleLastName', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Identitas Penduduk'}),
                    'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'id' : 'exampleInputEmail', 'placeholder' : 'Email Address', 'name' : 'email'}),
                    'nomor_hp' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'size':'4', 'maxlength':'12', 'class':'phone', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Handphone'}),
        }
```

and this is my models.py

```
userr = User()
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    nik = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    nomor_hp = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Create ModelB for every new ModelA."""
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user_id=instance)    
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=userr, weak=False,
                          dispatch_uid='models.create_profile')
```

Comment: what is `postingan` and `postingan2`?

Comment: Do you need them?

Comment: `user_form = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user , data=request.POST)` check this line, besides `user` would not be `instance`? You are probably getting an invalid error from this form avoiding code execution from your first condition

Comment: i use that to show my model in html @PruthviBarot

Comment: but it seem the same to instance

Comment: i already change to `profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=instance2)` and i try `profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)` this too, but its still not working @DiegoMagalhães

Comment: ok i will delete it, thanks @PruthviBarot

Answer (score 0):

you filtered profile objects based on User's pk

so do like this

```
def post_update(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return render(request, 'pengurusan/index.html')
    user_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    context={
        "user_form" : user_form,
        "profile_form" : profile_form,
        "user" : user,
        "profile" : user.profile,
    }
    return render(request, 'pengurusan/update-form.html', context)
```

so much stuff rectified. Please change in HTML template according to this context.

Comment: Since the relationship between user and profile is one-to-one, and it is an update (it is assumed that it already has an aggregated profile for that user) a query for the profile is unnecessary since it's possible to access it by the `user` instance with `user.profile`. A smart way to use it is `profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user.profile)`

Comment: i got this 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'profile'